# Scrape, simulate a click and scrape again with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Is there a way to scrape a webpage, simulate a click into that scraped webpage and get the result of that click using python?

Comment: maybe with a python wrapper for phantomjs or selenium

Comment: i did similar stuff using selenium (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org (also suggested by Pierre Emmanuel Lallemant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just use phantomjs with casperjs. Works very good.

[phantomjs.org](http://phantomjs.org)
[casperjs.org](http://casperjs.org)